# Wordpress list all posts grouped by tag for a given category

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a loop for getting all posts grouped by category for a given tag (see code below).  I need to turn it around and do the exact same thing but by tags for a given category.

In the code sample I am getting all posts tagged "torrington" and then doing a loop to display them grouped by category with an H2 of the category (e.g. "restaurants").

So in the reverse, I need to get all items category "restaurants" and then group them by tag (e.g. "torrington", "danbury" etc.).

```
<?php           
        // get all the categories from the database
        $cats = get_categories(); 
            // loop through the categries
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                // setup the cateogory ID
                $cat_id= $cat->term_id;

                // create a custom wordpress query
                query_posts("cat=$cat_id&tag=torrington&post_per_page=100");

                // start the wordpress loop!
                if (have_posts()) :     

                // Make a header for the category
                echo '<h2 class="cat-title">'.$cat->name.'</h2>';

                while (have_posts()) : 
                the_post(); ?>

                    <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
                    <div class="listing">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php //echo '<hr/>'; ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
            <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

EDIT:  I've gotten this far, but the query_posts statement seems to return nothing:

```
 <?php           
        // get all the categories from the database
        $tags = get_tags(); 
            // loop through the categries
            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                echo($tag->name);
                // setup the cateogory ID
                $tag_id = $tag->term_id;

                echo($tag_id);

                // create a custom wordpress query
                query_posts("tag_id=$tag_id&cat=eats&post_per_page=100");

                // start the wordpress loop!
                if (have_posts()) :     

                echo('posts');
                // Make a header for the category
                echo '<h2 class="cat-title">'.$tag->name.'</h2>';

                while (have_posts()) : 
                the_post(); ?>

                    <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
                    <div class="listing">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php //echo '<hr/>'; ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
            <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  It was simple change of `tag_id=$tag_id` not `tag=$tag_id`.

Code above updated.  Relevant line is `query_posts("tag_id=$tag_id&cat=eats&post_per_page=100");`